# Random button generator needs fixing to avoid loading the same page

Tags: javascript, css

I have a random button generator, named 'next event'. The button is okay however needs an improvement. Sometimes this button loads the same page the user is on multiple times, I'm not sure how to edit this, this is my code.
I could remove the current pages URL, however, this is in a separate JS document and I would like that to be loaded again on further button clicks.

the code used:

```js
    var sites = [
        '/landingpage/events/uk/boardmasters.html',
        '/landingpage/events/uk/reading.html',
        '/landingpage/events/uk/rizefest.html',
        '/landingpage/events/uk/bestival.html',
        '/landingpage/events/uk/creamfields.html',
        '/landingpage/events/uk/feastival.html',
        '/landingpage/events/uk/fusion.html',
        
    ];

    function randomSite() {
        var i = parseInt(Math.random() * sites.length);
        location.href = sites[i];
    }
```

Comment: so remove the current URL from the array?

Comment: If you keep throwing a dice long enough, you will get sequences of same numbers in a row. It's just good old randomness.

Comment: Very true, thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
function randomSite() {
var i = parseInt(Math.random() * sites.length);
 if(location.href !== sites[i])
     location.href = sites[i];
 else randomSite();
}
```

**UPDATE**

Based on the comment if you deleted URL within array I would change the function accordingly. And you don't need `pop()`

```
function randomSite() {
var i = parseInt(Math.random() * sites.length);
 if(location.pathname !== sites[i])
     location.pathname = sites[i];
 else randomSite();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, helps a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the current page from the `pages`-array before choosing a random item from it:

```
function randomSite() {
    var index = sites.indexOf(window.location.href);
    if (index > -1) {
      sites.splice(index, 1);
    }
    var i = parseInt(Math.random() * sites.length);
    location.href = sites[i];
}
```

Comment: Works great, thank you. Just need to fix certain bugs now ha! Thanks again for your quick reply.